# Rear Drum brake scraping and brake pulsating

Tags: brakes

I recently had a lug nut stud replaced on one of my rear tires. I believe they had to take apart the drum brake to remove the old stud and install the new one.

That same day I heard a scraping which increased in frequency as I sped up. I visually inspected the drum brake but didn't see anything out of place. The wheel cannot spin a full rotation when I jack up the car. It spins about 3/4 of the way freely then seems to catch on the brake.

Also I can feel a slight pulsating when I brake at around 15-25mph.

Any ideas of what I should be looking for?

UPDATE:

I finally got sick of the noise and replaced the brake drum, problem solved.

Comment: I can guess what happened. They had trouble getting the drum off, and either bent it prying it off, or dropped it once removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did they adjust your brake when they reinstalled it? Or just put it back together? Check the star-adjuster to see if it looks like it was extended out more then it should have.

Comment: yes actually, I did some brake work a few days before and had to bleed the brake lines and readjust them by backing up and braking. I would have thought over adjusting the brakes would cause them to always be rubbing though and not periodic

Comment: @shiznit123 I didn't see the periodic up there. What do you mean backing up and braking? If you replaced your pads, and did not reset your star adjuster, the brakes(assuming new pads) are running in a set up for worn pads. The adjuster is automatically extended as the pads wear to ensure the brakes always work.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. My car's rear brakes adjust by driving in reverse and applying the brake. I didn't replace the pads so I probably didn't need to adjust them in hind-sight. What I mean by periodic is that the scrapping only occurs at a specific point in the wheel's rotation.